# Why does 3,758,096,384 << 1 give 768

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

After reading the great answer for [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) 
I tested the claim (sic):

```
3,758,096,384 << 1
```

from Chrome console:

```
3,758,096,384 << 1

> 768

3,758,096,384 << 2

> 1536

3758096384 << 1

> -1073741824
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the comma operator at work. It's actually `384 << 1`. (The comma operator evaluates its left hand side, then evaluates its right hand side, and returns the right hand side.)

Answer (score 9):

It returns 768 because you're incorrectly using the comma operator. `3,758,096,384 << 1` will actually be `384 << 1` because the comma operator will return the last operand.