# C++ What does 'int x = (anyInt1, anyInt2);' mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does 3,758,096,384 << 1 gives 768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878572/why-does-3-758-096-384-1-gives-768)

Today I found out that following code compiles with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = (23,34);

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // prints 34

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this compiles? What is the meaning of (..., ...)?

Comment: Of course the real meaning is that some smart arse used the comma operator, which is very rarely justified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, `,` is an operator, and therefore `(23,34)` is an expression just like `(23+34)` is an expression. In the former, `,` is an operator, while in the latter, `+` is an operator.

So the expression `(23,34)` evaluates to the rightmost operand which is `34` which is why your code outputs `34`.

I would also like to mention that `,` is not an operator in a function call:

```
int m = max(a,b);
```

Here `,` acts a separator of arguments. It doesn't act as operator. So you pass two arguments to the function.

However,

```
int m = max((a,b), c);
```

Here first `,` is an operator, and second `,` is a separator. So you still pass two arguments to the function, not three, and it is equivalent to this:

```
int m = max(b, c); //as (a,b) evaluates to b
```

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Little note about parenthesis role in this example would be helpful as , operator has lower precedence then = operator. int x = 23,34; wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @Tomek: Good point. Thanks. Hope the readers will see your comment also.

Comment: This is also true for C.

Answer (score 14):

In an expression, the comma operator will evaluate all its operands and return the last. That's why in your example, `x` is equal to 34.

Comment: And the parenthesis are just like when used in if sentances for example, to group statements.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot that there is comma-operator in c++. thx