# Difference between "int i=1,2,3" and "int i=(1,2,3)" - variable declaration with comma operator

Tags: c

1. `int i=1,2,3;`
2. `int i=(1,2,3);`
3. `int i; i=1,2,3;`

What is the difference between these statements? I can't get to any particular reason for it.

Comment: Please improve your title. A future visitor with the same question will not find this question because the title conveys no indication what it is asking about. (Answer: Operator precedence.)

Comment: Raymond Chen - This is what i thought would be best for it. i would be thankful if you can edit please !

Comment: You honestly thought "What is the difference between two statements" is a good title? They could be any two statements!

Comment: It is very close to a duplicate of 'Please explain comma operator in this program', but the commas in the variable definition do distinguish this question from that.

Comment: @Raymond Chen- This is not duplicate.both are differenet !

Comment: @RaymondChen: Robert is new to the site and may not even know what those statements do.  Rather than berate someone, perhaps try to be more constructive and actually edit the question to provide a more descriptive title.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Then try [What does 'int x = (anyInt1, anyInt2);' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209399/c-what-does-int-x-anyint1-anyint2-mean).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - This is not duplicate.Please look carefully !

Comment: @Robert The *question* may not be an exact duplicate but the accepted answer in the other question gives the relevant explanation.

Comment: that means it's not duplicate !

Comment: a better duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/q/20163411/995714

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Statement 1 Result : Compile error.
```

'=' operator has higher precedence than ',' operator.
comma act as a separator here. the compiler  creates an integer variable 'i' and initializes it with '1'.
The compiler fails to create integer variable '2' as '2' is not a valid indentifer.

---

```
Statement 2 Result: i=3
```

'()' operator has higher precedence than '='. So , firstly, bracket operator is evaluated. '()' operator is operated from left to right. but it is always the result of last that gets assigned.

---

```
Statement 3: Result: i=1
```

'=' operator has higher precedence than ',' operator. so 'i' gets initialized by '1'. '2' and '3' are just constant expression. so have no effect .

Comment: +1 Good exaplanation. I'm going to remove my answer.

Comment: +1 from me for being thought provoking and urging me to try it for myself. Thank you for that.

Comment: In the first case, it's not a matter of operator precedence because the comma is not an operator. It's part of the syntax for declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It is the comma operator

```
i = a, b, c;            // stores a into i      ... a=5, b=2, c=3, i=5


i = (a, b, c);          // stores c into i      ... a=5, b=2, c=3, i=3
```

the differing behavior between the first and second lines is due to the comma operator having lower precedence than assignment.