# Why different behavior in two cases 1st. int i = 1,2,3; and 2nd. int i; i = 1,2,3;

Tags: c++, c, operators

Working on GCC compiler, with following two cases of operators in C program, observed different behaviors.

1.

```
 int i = 1,2,3;

 printf("%d",i);                     // this will give compile time error
```

And,

2.

```
int i;

i = 1,2,3;

printf("%d",i);    // Its output will be 1.
```

In 1st case compiler gave error "error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant".
And in second case, no errors, and output is 1.
Can anybody explain here the compiler behavior in both the cases in detail?
How does compiler interpret both statements?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: @haccks outputting 1 for me

Comment: @amdixon; I thought wrong. It will and should output `1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In the first case the comma separates *declaration and initialisation* of several variables of the same type:

   ```
   int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;
   ```

   You can add parentheses to tell the compiler it's an expression.

   ```
   int i = (1, 2, 3);
   ```

   If you combine them, it's easier to see why the comma is ambiguous without parentheses:

   ```
   int i = (1, 2, 3), j = 4, k = 5;
   ```
2. In the second case the comma separates 3 expressions.

   ```
   (i = 1), 2, 3
   ```

Comment: I was actually a bit surprised the first way didn't "work."

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's just a detail of the syntax, C++ doesn't really have operators with precedence, instead there are different types of expression, and the type of expression that has the comma operator isn't allowed in that context. Add some parens and it's OK though, `int i = (1, 2, 3);` works.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've added an example that shows why it doesn't work.

Comment: To be precise: there is nothing ambiguous about `i = 1, 2, 3`, because the comma has lower precedence than the assignment. Thus, the subexpressions are `i = 1`, `2`, and `3`. The entire expression has the sideeffect of assigning 1 to i and the value of 3.

Comment: In second case should't the output be `3`?

Comment: @haccks The whole expression evaluates to 3, but `i` is 1, e.g. in `j = (i=1,2,3)`, `i==1` and `j==3`