# warning: left hand operand of comma has no effect (c)

Tags: c

```
if (class == 'a','A')
```

I'm trying to continue only if the user inputs 'a' or 'A'. Every time I build it, it warns "left hand operand of comma has no effects".

I'm very new to C, so I apologize if I'm not specific enough or missing something obvious.

Comment: I strongly recommed you to read a C book to beginners...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209399/c-what-does-int-x-anyint1-anyint2-mean

Comment: The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's not how to do it , you should do instead

```
if(class == 'a' || class == 'A')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know why It worked the other way, even though it was wrong?

Comment: @Jeremy: It didn't *work*, but it did compile. The `,` is a *comma operator*. Consult your C text book to find out what that means. This: `(class == 'a', 'A')` is equivalent to: `((class == 'a'), 'A')`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the condition to

```
if ( class == 'a' || class == 'A' )
```

As for your original expression

```
if (class == 'a','A')
```

then there is used the comma operator and the value of expression is 'A'. As 'A' is not equal to zero then the condition will be always equal to true.  The expression before the comma is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst both current answers are correct, I think it may be more idiomatic to do:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if (tolower(class) == 'a')
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `if (class == 'a','A')`, the *left half* is the comparison `class == 'a'` and may evaluate to either `true` or `false` (in the boolean sense¹). The *right half* is just `'A'`, which is not equal to `0` and thus `true`. The left half gets evaluated but the result is not used. Then the right half is evaluated, and its "result" is `'A'`, which is `true`. Hence, the code acts as if you wrote

```
if (true)
   ...
```

You can check this by using a '0' at the right half:

```
if (class == 'a', 0)
    printf ("if-statement is true\n");
else
    printf ("if-statement is false\n");
```

and running this (after coercing the compiler to compile it) will indeed show the "false" line.

The compiler complains because the left half `class == 'a'` "does nothing": it has no side effect on `class` or on the result of the `if` statement. Thus, the compiler assumes this is a *mistake* and therefore issues the warning. It is a warning and not an error, because the syntax is correct. For comparison, you *are* allowed to write something similar such as

```
if (class = 'a', 'A')
    printf ("class == a,A seems to be true\n");
else
    printf ("That didn't work.\n");
```

which *has* a valid side effect (`class` gets the value for the character constant `'a'`) -- but it also will always state that it appears to be *true*, because the second half is what is passed on to the `if` statement.

---

¹ For C, I use `true` and `false` in the *boolean* sense only, as C has by default no concept of these named values without including `stdbool.h` (this defines the constants by name). The underlying concept is the same, though: an `if` statement evaluates its parameter, which is considered `false` if it evaluates to `0` (and thus will not execute the following expression), `true` if it evaluates to anything else than `0`.