# Boolean value not being returned correctly?

Tags: c++

Completely new "developer" here. I was tasked with writing a program which would give you the height of a ball falling from a tower, at each subsequent one second intervals. Unfortunately, the code doesn't actually stop and instead runs forever.

After some debugging I found the source of the problem: the fact that the bool ballGround, which should be returned as "true" once ballHeight < 0, doesn't seem to return correctly. It updates to "true" inside the printHeight function but reverts back to "false" once the program exits back into the getBallHeight function.

I've been looking to fix this for a few hours but haven't really found anything. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

bool printHeight(int seconds, double ballHeight, bool ballGround);

double getTowerHeight()
{
    double input{};
    std::cout << "Enter the height of the tower in meters: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}

double getBallHeight(int seconds, double towerHeight, bool ballGround)
{
    constexpr double gravity{ 9.8 };

    double distanceFallen{ (gravity * (seconds * seconds)) / 2 };
    double ballHeight{ towerHeight - distanceFallen };
    
    printHeight(seconds, ballHeight, ballGround);
    
    return (ballHeight, ballGround);
}

bool printHeight(int seconds, double ballHeight, bool ballGround)
{
    if (ballHeight > 0) {
        std::cout << "At " << seconds << " seconds, the ball is at height : " << ballHeight << " meters." << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "At " << seconds << " seconds, the ball is one the ground." << '\n';
        ballGround = true;
    }
    return ballGround;
}

int main()
{
    const double towerHeight{ getTowerHeight() }; 
    
    int i = 0;
    bool ballGround{ false };

    do {
        getBallHeight(i, towerHeight, ballGround);
        i++;
    } while (ballGround == false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `return (ballHeight, ballGround);` isn't doing what you think it is. And note that since `ballGround` is passed by value to `getBallHeight`,  it will *never* change back in `main`, and as a result, that loop is only going to execute once. `ballGround` was initialized to, and will remain, `false`, breaking the loop after the first pass.

Comment: you made a beginners mistake of writing too much code at once. I suggest you to remove almost everything and only keep a `do { modify_ballGround(ballGround); } while( ballGround == false);` in `main` and `modify_ballGround` should do nothing but modify the bool. This would be enough to not meet your expectations. Then read about pass by value vs pass by reference. And review the chapter about using function return values.

Comment: Regarding the use of the comma operator: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13209399/1025391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double getBallHeight(int seconds, double towerHeight, bool& ballGround)
{ 
...
}
```